# jQuery tablesorter doesn't work on columns having both numeric and strings

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using jQuery's tablesorter plugin to make the table sortable. It works fine on columns having one type of value i.e. either numeric or strings.  However, it doesn't work on columns having both types of values. e.g

### Column A(sorted down)

```
1  
2  
3  
Asi  
Libi  
Fabio
```

### Column A(sorted up)

```
Fabio  
Libi  
Asi  
3  
2  
1
```

What it's doing is treating the strings as one block and is preserving its order I suppose.

Can anyone help on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Because the column starts out with a number, tablesorter thinks that entire column contains only numbers. You can set the `header` option to change it to sort text.

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        headers: { 0 : { sorter: 'text' } }
    });
});
```

The main issue is if you are using the original tablesorter. It does not use a natural sorting algorithm, so the numbers `1`, `2`, and `10` will be sorted as `1, 10, 2`.

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), it uses a natural sort by default, so all you need to do is add a "sorter-text" class to the header ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/687/)):

HTML

```
<th class="sorter-text">ID</th>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    });
});
```